# Sketch the waves described by $y=(0.8\text{ meters})\sin[0.628(x-vt)]$

Tags: mathematical-physics

> Ocean waves with a crest to crest distance of $10$ meters can be described by the wave function $$y=(0.8\text{ meters})\sin[0.628(x-vt)]$$ where $v=1.2 \text{ meters/s}$.
>
> a) Sketch $y$ at $t=0$.
> b) Sketch $y$ at 2 seconds.

I believe this to have been in some way derived from the equation  $y = A \sin (\omega t + kx)$ where 0.8 is the amplitude of the wave.

I don't understand what the $x$ in this questions comes from. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is horizontal distance in the direction the wave is traveling.  $y$ is vertical displacement of the surface.  At a given $t$ you now have an equation $y=f(x)$ which you are being asked to graph.  You are correct that it will be a sine wave of amplitude ($0$ to peak) $0.8$ meters.  The change in $t$ will offset the origin of the sine wave.

Comment: So x is the movement of the wave on the horizontal axis, ok i understand that. What i cant understand is to plot y at 2 seconds the value of x at 2 seconds will need to be known, i have no idea how to find that.

Comment: At 2 seconds y=0.8sin(0.628*(x-2.4)

Comment: @andy07070:  that is correct.  Now just pick a number of points $x_i$ calculate $y_i$ from your equation, and plot them.  I would suggest a range of $x$ from $0$ through $10$.  Do this for each of the two equations.  They should look the same except one is shifted horizontally from the other by $2.4$

Comment: ahhhh of course, so foolish. thanks